# Video renders look pixelated

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

Ive been having this problem that my MP4 renders look chopped in final render.
I cant find the solution

This is in the render screen:

[image]

This is in the final render

[image]

---

Hey thanks for trying to help.
I checked those settings but no difference.
Here are my settings:
I just add movie and sound and render it so no prosessing

[image]

[image]

Comment: higher bit rate or codec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few possibilities, however it almost looks like option 2:

1. Video encoding:

[image]

2. Resolution (or % thereof)

[image]

3. Sampling

[image]

4. Actually check all of the Output and Render properties.
5. Are you are doing any post processing in Composition?

Comment: Setting the codec to H.264, output quality to high and encoding speed to good solved it. Thank you verry much!!!!!